# Installed Python 2.7, but Module in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages

Tags: installation, centos, python

I'm running CentOS, it already has Python2.6. I installed Python2.7 and I can see version `2.7` with `python -V`. I installed `demjson` module(`pip install demjson`) and then I try to execute the program. It is throwing the error like module wasn't found. I try to reinstall the module and got error like below

`DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): demjson in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages`

How can I resolve this issue. The modules are still in `2.6`

Answer (score -1):

I did the steps mentioned here, I have two versions of python! python2.6.6 and python2.7.8, but Im still figuing out how to install packages to specific versions! this might help.

https://dmngaya.com/2015/10/25/installing-python-2-7-on-centos-6-7/

yes!! followed the steps mentioned and it worked, you just need to link the paths! *cheers

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.